# how to display count() sql function using php

Tags: mysql, sql, count

how to display count()  sql function using php

```
  $results = "SELECT count(votesnumber) FROM `votes` WHERE `candidate_id`  = '$candidate_id'";
        $queryresults = mysqli_query($connect, $results);
        if($queryresults) {
        $rowresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresults);
        echo $rowresults['votesnumber'];

        } else {

            echo "error";

        }
```

i want to display the results of sql count() function using php. am counting specific columns WHERE ID = "some value" in phpmyadmin its working but with php its giving me headache . any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $results = "SELECT count(votesnumber) AS VoteNum FROM `votes` WHERE `candidate_id`  = '$candidate_id'";
    $queryresults = mysqli_query($connect, $results);
    if($queryresults) {
    $rowresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresults);
    echo $rowresults['VoteNum'];

    } else {

        echo "error";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to refer to the column name by a reference, then you need to give it a better name using an alias:

```
SELECT COUNT(votesnumber) as votesnumber
ROM `votes`
WHERE `candidate_id`  = '$candidate_id';
```

Second, you should not be munging query strings with parameter values.  Instead of `'$candidate_id'`, learn to use parameters.  This prevents unexpected syntax errors and SQL injection accounts.

Third, if `votesnumber` is actually a number of votes, then you probably want `SUM()` rather than `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "AS" instruction to your SQL if you want to get this data as a specific index from array (like `$rowresults['votes']`):

```
$results = "SELECT count(votesnumber) AS votes FROM `votes` WHERE `candidate_id`  = '$candidate_id'";
```

Remember that you can always `print_r()` (for arrays) or `var_dump()` your variable to check if it contains data you want to have.